# A contract inherit from a token contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, inheritance

I have a token contract(ERC20) A, then another contract B inherited from A (B is A). A contract C imported B.

questions are:

1. if I deployed B alone, is the address of this contract B represent the token A address?
2. if I deploy A first, then deploy B, are the tokens minted from A and the token minted from B the same?
3. if I deployed C alone, what's the address of Token A?
4. if I want to mint A token in C, what is the best way to do it?

Please please please help me. im so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since B inherits from A the deployed contract contains the methods from both A and B, so the same address can be used as both A and B
2. When contracts A and B are deployed separately you have two addresses that are unrelated. For example you can deploy the same contract twice and obtain two completely independent addresses.
3. If contract C imports B but it doesn't inherit from B then when C is deployed there's no A.

   If contract C inherits from B then 1. applies C address = B address = A address
4. Import A from contract C and pass A address as parameter in C constructor where you store a reference to A.

```
import "A.sol";

contract C {
    A token;

    constructor(A _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    function deposit(uint amount) public {
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: but _mint is a private function, how can i call mint in C without ineriting A?

Comment: @YeWang I can think two options: 1/ add a public method mint in A, and allow only C to call it, 2/ mint by owner and transfer to C so it doesn't have to mint, but I'm pretty sure there are many other ways to achieve something similar.